# MPAndroidChart : Only alternate labels are shown in x axis when more entries comes

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, axis-labels

In my android application i have a horizontal bar chart using MPAndroidChart.My problem is there are 12 number of bars in my bar chart each represents month from April to March,but i can see only alternate months label in x-axis.If there are small number of bars then i can see all the labels in x-axis.I didn't set any label count for x-axis using

xAxix.setLabelCount()

method.Then why i can't see all the labels? If I zoomed then i can see labels for each bar.I am using MPAndroidChart v3.0.1.Attached is the screenshot of the above.See here I can see only 'Apr,Jun,Aug,Oct,Dec,Feb' and all the other months are not displayed.How can I see all the other months also.

[image: Horizontal BarChart]

Below is my code.

```
        yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listChart.size(); i++){
        BarEntry newBEntry = new BarEntry(i,listChart.get(i).getAmount());
        xVals.add(listChart.get(i).getAltName());
        yVals1.add(newBEntry);
    }

    BarDataSet set1;
    set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");
    set1.setColors(new int[] {Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN});
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);
    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    data.setValueTextSize(10f);
    barChartIncExp.setData(data);

    barChartIncExp.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChartIncExp.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);

    barChartIncExp.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChartIncExp.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    barChartIncExp.setPinchZoom(true);
    barChartIncExp.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barChartIncExp.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
    barChartIncExp.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);

    XAxis xAxis = barChartIncExp.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); 
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            if(Math.round(value) >= xVals.size()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return xVals.get(Math.round(value));
            }
        }
    });


    YAxis leftAxis = barChartIncExp.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    leftAxis.setDrawLabels(false);

    YAxis rightAxis = barChartIncExp.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    rightAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);

    Legend l = barChartIncExp.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(false);

    barChartIncExp.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, Highlight highlight) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: hey can you let me know how did you get labels on both x and y axis

Comment: @payal_suthar I don't remeber exactly, looks likes xVals,yVals1 corresponds to the labels, not sure...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the number of labels you want to show in the `y-axis`.

```
XAxis xAxis=lineChart.getXAxis();

xAxis.setLabelCount(4,true); //4 is the number of values to be shown.
```

Comment: that resulted in following error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: I need to set labelcount as 11 instead of 12

Comment: may i know which version oh MpAndroid are u using

Comment: version 3.0.1.I have specified that in my question.If i set xAxis.setLabelCount(11,true); then i can see all the 12 months but now the labels are not coming in correct position of their respective bars.Now its difficult to understand which label for which bar..Earlier it was at the centre of each bar as in my screenshot.

Comment: Use xAxis.setGranularity(1f);

Comment: See my code above.Its already there.xAxis.setGranularity(1f);

Comment: xAxis.setLabelCount(4,true) its not the right answer,which will display all labels but will not center the label with respect to each bar.Correct answer is  xAxis.setLabelCount(4),don't use boolean true here,that solved the issue.

Comment: xAxis.setLabelCount(4,true) ; This line was Written on my app requirement. There you are supposed to change it to yours

Answer (score 5):

**Try This**

```
// where 12 is the number of bars in your chart.
xAxis.setLabelCount(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setLabelCount(label.size()+1, true);
```

Set the label count to the size of the label + 1 in the `xAxis.setLabelCount` function.
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
XAxis xAxis=lineChart.getXAxis();    
xAxis.setLabelCount(4,true);
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
```